# How to plot errorbars on this plot and change the overlay?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi have this dataset :

```
tdat=structure(list(Condition = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("AS", "Dup", "MCH"), class = "factor"), 
    variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Bot", "Top", "All"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(1.782726022, 1, 2.267946449, 1.095240234, 1, 1.103630141, 
    1.392545278, 1, 0.854984833, 4.5163067, 1, 4.649271897, 0.769428018, 
    1, 0.483117123, 0.363854608, 1, 0.195799358, 0.673186975, 
    1, 1.661568993, 1.174998373, 1, 1.095026419, 1.278455823, 
    1, 0.634152231)), .Names = c("Condition", "variable", "value"
), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = "data.frame")

> head(tdat)
  Condition variable    value
1        AS      Bot 1.782726
2       MCH      Bot 1.000000
3       Dup      Bot 2.267946
4        AS      Bot 1.095240
5       MCH      Bot 1.000000
6       Dup      Bot 1.103630
```

I can plot it like that using this code :

```
ggplot(tdat, aes(x=interaction(Condition,variable,drop=TRUE,sep='-'), y=value,
                 fill=Condition)) + 
                 geom_point() +
                 scale_color_discrete(name='interaction levels')+
        stat_summary(fun.y='mean', geom='bar',
                aes(label=signif(..y..,4),x=as.integer(interaction(Condition,variable))))
```

[image: http://postimg.org/image/5fwdwuu5t/]

**I have 2 questions :**

1. How to change the overlay so the black points are not hidden by the
   bar chart (3points should be visible per column)
2. How to add vertical errorbar on top of the bars using the standard
       deviation from the black points ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
tdat$x <- with(tdat,interaction(Condition,variable,drop=TRUE,sep='-'))
tdat_err <- ddply(tdat,.(x),
                  summarise,ymin = mean(value) - sd(value),
                            ymax = mean(value) + sd(value))

ggplot(tdat, aes(x=x, y=value)) + 
        stat_summary(fun.y='mean', geom='bar',
                aes(label=signif(..y..,4),fill=Condition)) + 
        geom_point() + 
        geom_errorbar(data = tdat_err,aes(x = x,ymin = ymin,ymax = ymax,y = NULL),width = 0.5) +
        labs(fill = 'Interaction Levels')
```

[image]

I've cleaned up your code somewhat. You will run into fewer problems if you move any extraneous computations outside of your ggplot() call. Better to create the new x variable first. Everything is more readable that way too.

The overlaying issue just requires re-ordering the layers.

Note that you were using `scale_colour_*` when you had mapped `fill` not `colour` (this is a very common error).

The only other "trick" was the un-mapping of `y`. Normally, when things get tricky I omit `aes` from the top level `ggplot` call entirely to make sure that each layer gets only the aesthetics that it needs.

The error bars again I tend to create the data frame outside of ggplot first. I find that cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: Once you know functions like `mean_sdl`, code using them is actually very easy to read.

Comment: @Roland Yeah, there's nothing wrong with `stat_summary`, it's just a personal preference of mine to make the df itself.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not much in favor of mixing error bars with a bar plot.

In ggplot2 geoms are drawn in the order you add them to the plot. So, in order to have the points not hidden, add them after the bars.

```
ggplot(tdat, aes(x=interaction(Condition,variable,drop=TRUE,sep='-'), y=value,
                 fill=Condition)) +  
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl", mult=1, geom="errorbar") +
  stat_summary(fun.y='mean', geom='bar') + 
  geom_point(show_guide=FALSE) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name='interaction levels')
```

[image]